# Javascript - Declaring an array a variable and slicing

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have an array of objects that I'm attempting to slice at a different index depending on the URL.

`data.Results.Data` is my array.

I declared a variable `arrList` to equal `data.Results.Data` when console.logging my `arrList` I see the results I am expecting.

When starting my condition and slicing at different indexes and then console.logging the array I am getting back the entire array not the sliced array I am expecting.

Here is my code:

```
function retrieveData(data) {
  const arrList = data.Results.Data;
  const urlStr = window.location.pathname;
  if (urlStr.includes("/states/")) {
    arrList.slice(23, 46);
    console.log(arrList, "Slice");
  } else if (urlStr.includes("/countries/")) {
    arrList.slice(46, 69);
    console.log(arrList, "Slice");
  } else if (urlStr.includes("/cities/")) {
    arrList.slice(69, 90);
    console.log(arrList, "Slice");
  }
}
```

I've tried declaring `arrList` inside of the condition statement which works, but I would like the variable `arrList` available throughout the entire scope of the function. I am expecting to see the sliced array when the condition is met.

Comment: is it typo or on purpose ?? `arrList.Slice` slice on caps

Comment: sorry it is not, should be arrList.slice. Has been edited

Comment: you can create a new variable and assign the original array to it then slice like that:
arr = arr.slice(beginning,end);
and to deep copy an object so you really keep the original intact you can do like that:
arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrList))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does not replace or modify the existing array.. You need to redefine it

`arrList = arrList.slice(69, 90)`

Else use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
function retrieveData(data) {
  const arrList = data.Results.Data;
  const urlStr = window.location.pathname;
  let slicedData = [];
  if (urlStr.includes("/states/")) {
    slicedData = arrList.slice(23, 46);
    console.log(arrList, "Slice");
  } else if (urlStr.includes("/countries/")) {
    slicedData = arrList.slice(46, 69);
    console.log(arrList, "Slice");
  } else if (urlStr.includes("/cities/")) {
    slicedData = arrList.slice(69, 90);
    console.log(arrList, "Slice");
  }
  return slicedData;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused about the redinfe part. I am trying to access the sliced array outside of the condition. if I am re-defining `arrList = arrList.slice` am I leaving the `arrList = data.Results.Data` variable at the start of the function?

Comment: yes u can do that. create a variable. I have update my answer check